# Default Values for Class Variables

Tags: php, class, properties, default

Let us say I have a class that looks like this:

```
class UserModel {
    private $_userData;
    function __construct($user_data){
          $this->_userData = $user_data;
    }
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
$user = json_decode('{"name":"Neal","surname":"MyLastName"}'); 
$the_user = new UserModel($user);
```

I do not want so that every time I want to get the user's name to have to do `$this->_userData->name` inside the class.

Is it ok if i set a default value for name and surname, and chreate a `__get()` function like so:

```
class UserModel {
    private $_userData;
    private $name = 'default';
    private $surname = 'default';
    function __construct($user_data){
          $this->_userData = $user_data;
    }


    function __get($var){
         if(isset($this->_userData->$var))return $this->_userData->$var; // new storage
         if(isset($this->$var))return $this->$var; // old storage
         return null; // the default (could be a throw new Exception() instead)
    }
}
```

Here is a demo of what I am trying to do: http://codepad.viper-7.com/cuS9Lx

Comment: I'm not sure I see what the question really is? There is nothing wrong what what you are doing, and if it suits your needs do it.  Mind you you might want to use `protected` not `private` variables.

Comment: **Note:** When it comes to performance, it would be interesting to know how much time it takes to do the various isset()'s above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is exactly how you would want to do it. Personally, if I had defaults, I would place them all on the class level, and then retrieve them that way:

```
class Foo
{
     static $bar = 1;
     private $_udata;
     public function __get($a)
     {
          return (isset($this->_udata->$a))?
                    $this->_udata->$a:
                    self::$$a; // NOTE DOUBLE $!
     }
};
$f = new Foo(); echo $f->bar; // 1
```

It has a lower footprint, and it has more of "Resolve to default" feel.

Comment: Hmm, since we are only reading defaults, it makes sense to be static instead of copy of it in each instance. Good point.

Comment: On the other hand, setting as static is a bit counter intuitive visually.

Comment: Well, in this case, I would probably have a "default user" which was a private, static property of the user class. I would likely make it a simple array, so that the lookup could be `self::$defaul_user[$var]`

Answer (score 0):

(1) Extended boring answer:

Json standard functions for PHP generate objects "on the fly" with their own "internal classes", so:

```
$user = json_decode('{"name":"Neal","surname":"MyLastName"}');
```

Will generate internally something like this:

```
//class object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
class tempclass343434 {
    public $name;
    public $surname;
}

$user = new tempclass343434();
$user->name = "Neal";
$user->surname = "MyLastName";
```

NOT your "UserModel" class.

(2) Quick answer:

There are some PHP libraries, that allow you serialize and unserialize using your classes, you may want to browse the web a little bit. Sorry, I don't have the links right now.

(3) You may also want to make your own JSON methods, but its more complicated:

```
class UserModel {
    // ...

    public $name;
    public $surname;

    // ...

    /* string */ function ExportToJson() { $Result = "";  ... return $Result; }
    /* void */ function ImportToJson(/* String */ JSONValue) { ... }
} // UserModel
```

Cheers.

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode('{"name":"Chris"}'));` would print `object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Chris" }`, so there is no custom class; it is the default PHP class (**stdClass**). The whole point of this question is to *convert* or *wrap* those properties into a `UserModel` class (by setting the properties directly, for example).

Comment: @Neal No, I say you didn't known O.O.P. Im telling you that those JSON+PHP functions don't use your own classes, they generate their own classes, using an example.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras, Ok, its (stdClass)#1, but its still not "UserModel". I suggest Neal to look for existing functions / libraries (I have seen, buit don't have the link) or make their own. We are saying the same basic concepts with different words ;-)